# Split string based on specific characters

Tags: c#, string, list, substring

I want to split a string using a comma (,) and add it to a list. But this is not applicable if the comma is following 2 backslashes.

Eg:

`aaa,aaa,aaa` >> Split string into 3 >> `(aaa) (aaa) (aaa)`

`aa\\,a,aaa` >> Split string into 2 >> `(aa\\,a) (aaa)`

I realize I can do this using sub strings by traversing through the characters one by one but I don't think that's efficient (specially for a long string).

Is there a quicker and more efficient way to accomplish this using in C#?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can check the characters before 2 index of your comma they are `\\\` or not.

Comment: Yes, I can do that but as I have mentioned, it's not efficient for long strings. I was wondering if there was a smarter way to do this.

Comment: While i have a general understanding of what your problem is, it still is somewhat ambiguous to me. How would you need to split strings like `aa\\\,bb` or `aa\\\\,bb`? (would these be valid cases?)

Comment: I have edited the examples. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @John, your edited answers unfortunately does not unambiguously explain how you would need to deal with strings like `aa\\\,bb` or `aa\\\\,bb` -- please tell exactly what the results of splitting these two strings should be (or whether those two strings would even be possible or valid as input...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regular expression will work:

```
string input = @"aaa\\,aaa,aaa";
var re = new Regex(@"(?<!\\),");
string[] parts = re.Split(input);
```

Basically it says to split on each comma, except for commas that are preceeded by two backslashes, as per your requirements.

Here's a different way to write that code that gives you some comments for future maintenance:

```
string input = @"aaa\\,aaa,aaa";
var re = new Regex(@"
    (?<!      # negative lookahead, ie. 'is not preceeded by'
        \\    # two backslashes
    )         # end of negative lookahead
    ,         # the comma to split on
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
string[] parts = re.Split(input);
```

---

To add the strings to an existing list, do this:

```
list.AddRange(re.Split(input));
```

To construct a new list, instead of an array, do this:

```
List<string> = re.Split(input).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm trying to add the split strings to a list (not an array). How would you change this line to accommodate this: `string[] parts = re.Split(input);`

Comment: Updated answer, see bottom.

Answer (score 3):

A good way would be to use a regular epxression with a [negative lookbehind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var test1 = @"aaa,aaa,aaa";
var test2 = @"aa\\,a,aaa";

var pattern = @"(?<!\\),";

Regex.Split(test0, pattern); // returns ["aaa", "aaa", "aaa"]
Regex.Split(test1, pattern); // returns [@"aa\\,a", "aaa"]
```

The `(?<!\\)` is a negative lookbehind, which means the next character only matches if the last two previous ones aren't `\\`.